# dual ramp voltmeter meaningfully displaying the microvolt digit

Tags: frequency, voltage-measurement, dual

How can a common dual ramp voltmeter meaningfully display the microvolt digit when measuring a DC voltage ridden by a 50 Hz signal of several millivolts captured from the power distribution network.

Comment: Sounds VERY like a homework question. These are OK BUT you should say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting the integration period as an integer number of mains-frequency cycles.